# Mongoose: Referencing a subdocument from another subdocument AND population

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a document model called **school** which in turn has two subdocuments:

1. students
2. class

Each student belongs to one class.

```js
var classSchema = new Schema({
 name: {type : String}
});

var studentSchema = new Schema({
 name : {type : String, required:true},
 class: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Institute.classes' },
});

var schoolSchema = new Schema({
 name : {type : String, required:true},
 students : [studentSchema],
 classes : [classSchema]
});

var School = mongoose.model('School', schoolSchema);
```

Now when I am fetching a student, I want to populate the class as well. I am doing this as:

```js
var school_id = req.params.school_id;
var student_id = req.params.student_id;

School
    .findOne({'_id': school_id, 'students._id': student_id})
    .populate({path: 'students.class'})
    .exec(function (err, data) {
        done(err, data);
    });
```

When I do this, I get following error:

```
"message": "Schema hasn't been registered for model \"School.classes\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)",
"name": "MissingSchemaError"
```

Is is possible to populate a subdocument from another subdocument?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: may be it is not possible using populate, but you try aggregate

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar That won't work in my opinion. Aggregate is for the operation on the fetched response data while I want the data to be populated from other sub-doc.

Comment: $lookup used for joint in aggregate and it is possible